# Evaluating a compiled expression tree is sometimes slower

Tags: cil

I generate an expression tree containing simple math expressions. The expression types are limited to constants, variables, addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, negation, sqrt and a few trigonometric functions. Variables are like constants, but their values can change.

To evaluate the tree, I iterate from bottom to top and perform the operation indicated by the expression type. This involves switching on the expression type, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    ref Expr expr = ref expressions[i];
    switch (expr.Type) {
        case Op.Addition:
            expr.Value = expressions[expr.Operand1].Value + expressions[expr.Operand2].Value;
            break;
        case ...
    }
}
```

I also evaluate the derivatives using reverse automatic differentiation. This involves iterating the tree from top to bottom and computing the adjoint for each expression. There are simple rules for each expression type:

```
ref Expr root = ref expressions[expressions.Length - 1];
root.Adjoint = 1.0;

for (int i = expressions.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    ref Expr expr = ref expressions[i];
    switch (expr.Type) {
        case Op.Addition:
            ref Expr left = ref expressions[expr.Operand1];
            ref Expr right = ref expressions[expr.Operand2];
            left.Adjoint += expr.Adjoint;
            right.Adjoint += expr.Adjoint;
            break;
        case ...
    }
}
```

To avoid the branching, I thought that I'd compile this expression tree by generating IL code. To do this, I again iterate from bottom to top through the tree and emit instructions for calculating the expression values. Similarly, I iterate from top to bottom and emit instructions for calculating the adjoints. I then end up with two big functions that compute the values and adjoints for all expressions without any branching.

```
var method = new DynamicMethod("Evaluate", typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(double[]) }, true);
var il = method.GetILGenerator();

for (int i = 0; i < expressions.Length; ++i) {
    ref Expr expr = ref expressions[i];
    switch (expr.Type) {
        case Op.Addition:
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, expr.Index);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, expr.Operand1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_R8);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, expr.Operand2);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_R8);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_R8);
        case ...
    }
}

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
evaluate = method.CreateDelegate<EvaluateFunction>();
```

For small expression trees, this proved to be quite effective. The time to evaluate the tree was quite significantly reduced. However, for larger expression trees the compiled evaluation function actually becomes slower.

[image]

Why could this be? Clearly, for large expression trees, the compiled function can contain a large number of instructions. Is this then simply due to the size of the instruction cache? There is no branching in the function, so I'd have thought that the instructions could be loaded very efficiently.

Comment: Perhaps there is something that happens during the compilation that makes it inefficient. We'd need more informaion about how you compile it.

Comment: I added a snippet showing how I emit the instructions using `ILGenerator`.